# FreeMarkerViewResolver not render the template when i request use ajax

Tags: spring, freemarker

Sorry everyone. My english is so bad,but i have some questions to ask.
When i try to use ajax get a freemarker view.It's not render just html code.
The following is my config.
springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="freemakerViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"></property>
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="request" />
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true" />
</bean>
```

freeMarkerConfigurer

```
<bean id="freeMarkerConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="template_update_delay">0</prop>
            <prop key="default_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="number_format">0.##########</prop>
            <prop key="datetime_format">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</prop>
            <prop key="date_format">yyyy-MM-dd</prop>
            <prop key="time_format">HH:mm:ss</prop>
            <prop key="classic_compatible">true</prop>
            <prop key="template_exception_handler">ignore</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

- my view

  `<ul>
      <#list items as item>
          <li>item.name</li>
      </#list>
  </ul >`
- response data

`<ul></ul >`

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my wrong.I submit the wrong parameters,so the list is empty.